# WinDbg !heap command not working on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, windbg

I an trying to inspect the unmanaged heap on a Windows Azure Web Role using WinDBG. When running "!heap -s", I am getting the "Invalid type information" error, same as outlined in this question: [WinDbg !heap command not working due to missing symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941862/windbg-heap-command-not-working).

However, when trying to reload the symbols and setting symbol loading to "noisy", I see this:

SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/9D7437C73CAF42919078F59C14F1BB462/ntdll.pdb not found

So AFAIK, there are no symbols for this particular version of ntdll.

Is there any workaround that would enable me to be able to see the unmanaged heap? My WaIISHost.exe process is consuming 1.5GB of RAM and the managed heap is tiny (50MB).

Comment: Symbols should be on symbol server, Check here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5408a35-f097-4006-9c95-bf1802d03ead/no-symbols-for-ntdlldll-on-microsofts-symbol-server-kb2882822?forum=windbg

Comment: Thanks, I've reached out to windbgfb@microsoft.com as per the thread you've referenced.

Comment: David, if you have an Azure support contract you can open an incident via the portal and the support team can help you out with this.

Comment: Good idea. However, at this point I got a response from windbgfb saying they will contact the Azure team and find out more, so I guess I'm on a right track :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the Windows symbols are actually missing on Microsoft's symbol servers - the best indication is the "not found" error from the Symbol Server when noisy loading is set.

In this case, one should contact the public Windbg External Feedback alias - windbgfb@microsoft.com. I did this in my case (for ntdll.dll version is 6.1.7601.18241) and Microsoft resolved the problem in about a week's time.